# Using Cauchy’s Theorem/ Cauchy’s Integral Formula for Higher Derivatives or otherwise, evaluate, with justification, the following integrals:

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

$$\int \frac{5 \cos(\pi z)}{(z+3i)(z-7i)}dz$$

i) where γ is the circle centre 0 and radius 4;

ii)γ is the circle centre 0 and radius 10

For part i) I have calculated using CIF that because z=-3i is only valid in γ that f(z)=(5cos(πz))/(z-7i) and so

$$\int \frac{5 \cos(\pi z)}{(z+3i)}dz =-\pi \cos(-3\pi i)$$

However for part ii) because both $z=-3i$ and $ z=7i$ are valid in γ I do not know what to set as my f(z).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either split your contour in 2, or use partial fractions.

If $\gamma_1$ is the right half side of the contour, $\gamma_2$ is the left half side, and $\gamma_3$ is vertically bisecting the contour, we see $$\oint _{\gamma} \frac{5cos(\pi z)}{(z+3i)(z-7i)} = \oint_{\gamma_1+\gamma_3}\frac{\frac{5cos(\pi z)}{z+3i}}{z-7i}+ \oint_{\gamma_2-\gamma_3} \frac{\frac{5cos(\pi z)}{z-7i}}{z+3i} $$ Evaluating both component integrals thru Cauchy Integral Formula gives $$2\pi i (\frac{5cos(\pi 7i)}{7i+3i})+ 2\pi i(\frac{5cos(-\pi 3i)}{-3i-7i})= \pi cos (\pi 7i) - \pi cos (-\pi 3i)$$ and simplify. This is essentially the residue theorem using CIF.

You could also just decompose into partial fractions and solve using the same contour, but that’s more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if you want use Cauchy (using residues is better), do a partial fraction decomposition of $5/(z+3i)(z−7i)$.

Comment: why is the cos(πz) not included in this partial fraction decomposition?